# Unable to select more than 1 row in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am unable to select more than 1 row from a sql table.
I can only do

```
Select top 1 * from [table_name]
```

or

```
Select [pk_table] from [table_name].
```

Any other command just keeps processing and the table only has about 300 records with 10 columns.

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb1](
    [myid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cl1] [int] NULL,
    [cl2] [int] NULL,
    [cl3] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [cl4] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [cl5] [tinyint] NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_tb1_Tbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [myid] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem here since same table schema is working in other database.

Comment: Does it keep processing if you do SELECT TOP 2 * FROM [Table_Name] as well, or does it work as long as you specify?

Comment: What other commands for example? Does an added `order by [column_name]`work?

Comment: yes it does not return anything and keeps processing for above case and order by also does not work

Comment: Can you supply an example of the table? What columns it has and what data.

Comment: Maybe an open uncomitted transaction has a lock on the second row that would be scanned. When the command "keeps processing" what does `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` say that session is waiting on?

Comment: Try select count(*).  You may have some corrupt data.  Try dbcc checkedb

Comment: I tried count(*) and it gave me the total records but could not select those records(since select query is not working).

Comment: it was a deadlock that ended on killing that process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to find out running queries in your DB:

```
select
    p.spid
,   right(convert(varchar, 
            dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, P.last_batch, getdate()), '1900-01-01'), 
            121), 12) as 'batch_duration'
,   P.program_name
,   P.hostname
,   P.loginame
from master.dbo.sysprocesses P
where P.spid > 50
and      P.status not in ('background', 'sleeping')
and      P.cmd not in ('AWAITING COMMAND'
                    ,'MIRROR HANDLER'
                    ,'LAZY WRITER'
                    ,'CHECKPOINT SLEEP'
                    ,'RA MANAGER')
order by batch_duration desc
```

Comment: I got one result for this which is the same that i get when using this  query "Select * from master.dbo.sysprocesses".

Comment: The above query returns only currently running queries which might deadlock other queries for resources, if you have got only one result that means only your query is running on the server which means its problem with your query.